# DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendOptional multiple ISO standards results in DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, java-14, datetimeformatter

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
        DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        
        LocalDateTime x = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-10-11T07:00:53.004Z", dtf.toFormatter());
        System.out.println("After formatting: " + x);  
  }  
}
```

so i was curious why this does not work, it seems like he automatically assumes the first one to not be optional? if i swap offset_date_time and local_date_time it parses this string but not the local_date_time string

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-10-11T07:00:53.004Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2053)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:493)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

im on Java 14 if that makes any difference, i would be happy to provide additional information if necassery

in the end i changed the methode too, to allow all 3 of the ISO standards:

```
 public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {  
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'T'"))
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("XXX"));
            
            LocalDateTime x = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-10-11T07:00:53.004Z", dtf.toFormatter());
            System.out.println("After formatting: " + x);  
      }  
    }
```

Comment: You problem is with the Z character , you can put the Z between 'Z' , and use a simple declaration for your formatter  example : DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD `Z` is an offset (of zero) from UTC and needs to be parsed as an offset. The offset could also be like `+02:00` or `+00:00`, so hardcoding a literal `Z` will not work always.

Comment: Yes , my comment will work only with offset of zero, so it not the great choice  ,   thanks for your feedback  :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is because the first optional part **can be fully consumed**, so the `DateTimeFormatter` consumes the text denoted by the `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.

Then, the two remaining optional patterns are tried against the remaining text, which is `Z`, but they cannot be matched.

At last, there is no pattern left to parse, so the parser notes that the text `Z` is left unparsed, hence an exception is thrown.

Comment: the two remaining patterns are tried against the text Z or the full text?

Comment: No, text which is already consumed, will not be parsed again. So `2021-10-11T07:00:53.004` is consumed by the `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` optional pattern.

Comment: then i understand where i went wrong, i wasnt aware it allows for partial consumption, i thought i could just match it to difference patterns. i will just have to make it easier by appending the difference of each pattern. thanks!